# md5 for iso checks, but burn always fails

Tags: system-installation, dvd, burning, k3b, optical

---------------------update-------------------------

the disc shows as an excellent disc:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ cdck -t -v
Track list (1-1):
  1: 00:02:00 (sec: 000000) data 
170: 82:48:60 (sec: 372510) data (leadout)

Disc status: data mode 1
Multisession: 0
Audio status: failed to get, reason: Input/output error

Try to find out what sort of CD this is...
CD-ROM with iso9660 fs
iso9660: 727 MB size, label 'KIWI CD/DVD Installation        '
Creating software: '0xc1c764e9'
bootable CD   

NB! For disks written with some burners cdck might 
    report about unreadable sectors at the end of the disk.
    In such cases you can just ignore those warnings.

Reading sectors 1-372510
372508 ok

CD overall:
   Sectors total: 372510:
   Good sectors: 372510:
   Bad sectors (incl. with poor timing): 0
CD timings:
   Minimal = 0 usec (0.000000s)
   Maximal = 45445 usec (0.045445s)
   Average = 186 usec (0.000186s)

Conclusion:
   Excellent disc!
thufir@doge:~$
```

however, the burn always reports as failure.  Failure of what is unclear.  The md5 checks out as fine.

---------------------end update------------------------------------------

I'm burning a Linux ISO, [ViciBox](http://download.vicidial.com/iso/vicibox/server/), from Ubuntu.  I've gone through a few DVD's, and am now just simulating burning to disc with K3B.  I don't see a particular failure message:

```
Burned media
-----------------------
DVD-R Sequential

Devices
-----------------------
TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-222AL SB01 (/dev/sr0, CD-R, CD-RW, CD-ROM, DVD-ROM, DVD-R, DVD-RW, DVD-R DL, DVD+R, DVD+RW, DVD+R DL) [DVD-ROM, DVD-R Sequential, DVD-R Dual Layer Sequential, DVD-R Dual Layer Jump, DVD-RAM, DVD-RW Restricted Overwrite, DVD-RW Sequential, DVD+RW, DVD+R, DVD+R Dual Layer, CD-ROM, CD-R, CD-RW] [SAO, TAO, RAW, SAO/R96P, SAO/R96R, RAW/R16, RAW/R96P, RAW/R96R, Restricted Overwrite, Layer Jump] [%7]

System
-----------------------
K3b Version: 2.0.2
KDE Version: 4.14.1
QT Version:  4.8.6
Kernel:      3.16.0-23-generic

Used versions
-----------------------
growisofs: 7.1

growisofs
-----------------------
Executing 'builtin_dd if=/dev/fd/0 of=/dev/sr0 obs=32k seek=0'
/dev/sr0: engaging DVD-R DAO upon user request...
/dev/sr0: reserving 372510 blocks
, warning for short DAO recording
/dev/sr0: "Current Write Speed" is 16.4x1352KBps.
     491520/762900480 ( 0.1%) @0.0x, remaining 129:15 RBU 100.0% UBU   6.3%
     491520/762900480 ( 0.1%) @0.0x, remaining 206:49 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
     491520/762900480 ( 0.1%) @0.0x, remaining 310:13 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
     491520/762900480 ( 0.1%) @0.0x, remaining 387:46 RBU 100.0% UBU 100.0%
   15204352/762900480 ( 2.0%) @3.2x, remaining 14:45 RBU 100.0% UBU  99.1%
   46792704/762900480 ( 6.1%) @6.8x, remaining 5:36 RBU 100.0% UBU  99.1%
   73433088/762900480 ( 9.6%) @5.8x, remaining 3:54 RBU 100.0% UBU  99.1%
  105971712/762900480 (13.9%) @7.0x, remaining 2:53 RBU 100.0% UBU  98.9%
  139034624/762900480 (18.2%) @7.2x, remaining 2:23 RBU 100.0% UBU  99.1%
  166461440/762900480 (21.8%) @5.9x, remaining 2:05 RBU 100.0% UBU  98.9%
  200409088/762900480 (26.3%) @7.3x, remaining 1:46 RBU 100.0% UBU  98.4%
  234848256/762900480 (30.8%) @7.5x, remaining 1:34 RBU 100.0% UBU  99.1%
  264503296/762900480 (34.7%) @6.4x, remaining 1:24 RBU 100.0% UBU  82.2%
  299859968/762900480 (39.3%) @7.7x, remaining 1:14 RBU 100.0% UBU  98.9%
  335740928/762900480 (44.0%) @7.8x, remaining 1:06 RBU  99.9% UBU  98.9%
  368607232/762900480 (48.3%) @7.1x, remaining 0:58 RBU 100.0% UBU  95.9%
  403570688/762900480 (52.9%) @7.6x, remaining 0:51 RBU 100.0% UBU  98.1%
  440860672/762900480 (57.8%) @8.1x, remaining 0:45 RBU 100.0% UBU  98.9%
  478642176/762900480 (62.7%) @8.2x, remaining 0:38 RBU  99.9% UBU  98.7%
  516915200/762900480 (67.8%) @8.3x, remaining 0:32 RBU 100.0% UBU  98.9%
  555712512/762900480 (72.8%) @8.4x, remaining 0:26 RBU 100.0% UBU  98.7%
  595001344/762900480 (78.0%) @8.5x, remaining 0:21 RBU 100.0% UBU  98.7%
  634781696/762900480 (83.2%) @8.6x, remaining 0:15 RBU 100.0% UBU  98.7%
  675053568/762900480 (88.5%) @8.7x, remaining 0:10 RBU 100.0% UBU  98.7%
  715849728/762900480 (93.8%) @8.8x, remaining 0:05 RBU 100.0% UBU  98.6%

growisofs command:
-----------------------
/usr/bin/growisofs -Z /dev/sr0=/dev/fd/0 -use-the-force-luke=notray -use-the-force-luke=tty -use-the-force-luke=4gms -use-the-force-luke=tracksize:372510 -use-the-force-luke=dummy -use-the-force-luke=dao:372510 -dvd-compat -speed=16 -use-the-force-luke=bufsize:32m
```

Notably, K3B does confirm the md5 sum:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ md5sum Vicibox_v.6.0.x86_64-6.0.3.preload.iso 
d676e7c90f2f716c2844a507a52686b2  Vicibox_v.6.0.x86_64-6.0.3.preload.iso
thufir@dur:~$
```

which matches the md5sum:

http://download.vicidial.com/iso/vicibox/server/Vicibox_v.6.0.x86_64-6.0.3.preload.md5

---------------on topic-------------------------------

no, I'm not asking about a different distro, I just want to burn this ISO from Ubuntu and am trying to understand the debugging output.

Comment: while the K3B pop-up window reports "error", I don't see any actual error logged above...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

------update-----

After the medium was tested and rated "excellent":

If the MD5 from DVD-R matches the MD5 of the ISO, then the burn run succeeded.
The DVD is supposed to work for its purpose of booting. Did you already try ?

It looks like the error message from K3B is mislead. (Shrug)

------end update-----

> burn always fails

What symptoms tell you that it failed ?

I guess you cannot read it, but even that can have
various reasons. If the medium stays just blank without
any other error indication, then either you have
inadvertedly enabled simulation or your burner drive
is going bad.

The state of the medium may be inquired by

```
dvd+rw-mediainfo /dev/sr0
```

---

Since you just want to burn an ISO, i propose you
make further experiments by skipping the GUI layer
and starting growisofs directly.
The following proposal is derived from the growisofs
command reported by K3B. Excute it in the directory
where the ISO ist stored (or use its absolute path):

```
growisofs -Z \
          /dev/sr0=Vicibox_v.6.0.x86_64-6.0.3.preload.iso \
          -use-the-force-luke=notray \
          -use-the-force-luke=dao \
          -dvd-compat \
          -speed=16 \
          -use-the-force-luke=bufsize:32m
```

The option

```
-use-the-force-luke=dummy
```

causes burn simulation on DVD-R, which of course would
prevent real burn success.

Have a nice day :)

Thomas

Comment: k3b says "error", but I can't an error log.  I included the log which I was able to find.  It's not clear what the error is.

Comment: Then examine the DVD. By above dvd+rw-mediainfo run, and by a run of: dd if=/dev/sr0 bs=2048 count=372510 | md5sum . The number 372510 is the size of the .iso file divided by 2048.

Comment: see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183052/install-just-goes-to-a-blank-or-black-screen    the DVD's seem fine.

Answer (score 1):

ViciBox v.6 is based on OpenSUSE 13.1 so there should be no problems putting the ViciBox iso on a USB flash drive using UNetbootin from the Ubuntu Software Center. OpenSUSE is on UNetbootin's list of compatible distros. You should reformat the USB flash drive as FAT32 in GParted first if you have ever used the USB flash drive to boot a Linux distro.

UNetbootin has been dropped from the Ubuntu 18.04 repositories. When I tested the built-in Startup Disk Creator application as a UNetbootin replacement app with a non-*buntu live .iso image it worked  in Ubuntu 18.04.

Also see: [Trouble installing openSUSE 13.1 via live USB](https://superuser.com/questions/688261/trouble-installing-opensuse-13-1-via-live-usb). Since the ViciBox v.6 iso file that you downloaded is 728MB, a 2GB USB flash drive should be large enough to make a bootable USB ViciBox flash drive.