# How to compare a DVD to an ISO?

Tags: dvd, iso, burning

When I boot the (non-Ubuntu) DVD from the burned ISO, it starts to install, then gives a blank screen.

Is it possible to compare the DVD to the ISO?  Apparently, only if you compare an exact number of bytes??

Here's an ISO I downloaded:

```
$ md5sum Vicibox_v.6.0.x86_64-6.0.3.preload.iso
d676e7c90f2f716c2844a507a52686b2 Vicibox_v.6.0.x86_64-6.0.3.preload.iso
```

which matches http://download.vicidial.com/iso/vicibox/server/Vicibox_v.6.0.x86_64-6.0.3.md5

the burned cd seems ok:

```
$ cdck -t -v
Track list (1-1):
1: 00:02:00 (sec: 000000) data
170: 82:48:60 (sec: 372510) data (leadout)

Disc status: data mode 1
Multisession: 0
Audio status: failed to get, reason: Input/output error

Try to find out what sort of CD this is...
CD-ROM with iso9660 fs
iso9660: 727 MB size, label 'KIWI CD/DVD Installation '
Creating software: '0xc1c764e9'
bootable CD

NB! For disks written with some burners cdck might
report about unreadable sectors at the end of the disk.
In such cases you can just ignore those warnings.

Reading sectors 1-372510
372508 ok

CD overall:
Sectors total: 372510:
Good sectors: 372510:
Bad sectors (incl. with poor timing): 0
CD timings:
Minimal = 0 usec (0.000000s)
Maximal = 59 usec (0.000059s)
Average = 0 usec (0.000000s)

Conclusion:
Excellent disc!
```

the hardware:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx0 port B) (rev 02)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port D)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port H)
00:0a.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx1 port A)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (rev 40)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:15.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
00:15.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2)
00:15.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3)
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Curacao XT [Radeon R9 270X]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
02:00.0 USB controller: Etron Technology, Inc. EJ168 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 IDE interface: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9172 SATA III 6Gb/s RAID Controller (rev 11)
04:0e.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller (rev c0)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
06:00.0 USB controller: Etron Technology, Inc. EJ168 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
08:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 04)
09:04.0 Multimedia audio controller: C-Media Electronics Inc CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio]
```

When it goes to install the OS (not Ubuntu) I just get a blank screen.

How do I compare the burned DVD against the ISO?

see also:

[md5 for iso checks, but burn always fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580624/md5-for-iso-checks-but-burn-always-fails)

which I'm taking a closer look at again.  I'm thinking of booting the ISO from the hard drive.

-------------------------------update----------------------------------------------

dd checks out:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ dd if=/dev/cdrom of=/tmp/Vicibox_test.iso
1490040+0 records in
1490040+0 records out
762900480 bytes (763 MB) copied, 70.4178 s, 10.8 MB/s
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$  md5sum /tmp/Vicibox_test.iso
d676e7c90f2f716c2844a507a52686b2  /tmp/Vicibox_test.iso
thufir@doge:~$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just `dd` the DVD contents to a new ISO and compare it to the original ISO:

```
dd if=/dev/cdrom of=/tmp/Vicibox_test.iso
md5sum /tmp/Vicibox_test.iso
```

If you get the same MD5SUM then the optical drive is capable of reading the media without errors.

Comment: it checks out actually

Comment: I think it's a DVD drive problem:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182988/